# What does 「て」 mean in 「読んでて」 (te-form + て)?

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, colloquial-language

It's a sentence from Tae Kim's grammar guide:

> 崇君{たかしくん}は漫画{まんが}ばっかり読{よ}んで**て**さ。 かっこ悪{わる}い。

The 「て」 that appears after the te-form of 「読む」 and before 「さ」, what is it and what effect does it give? Possibly a colloquial-only thing?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「読んで**て**」 is the very common colloquial contraction of 「読んで**いて**」.  This elision of 「い」 happens all the time when we are speaking.

Contrary to what seems to me a popular belief among J-learners, we use 「～～て/でいる」 verb form to describe a habitual action.  (I have seen/heard ***many*** J-learners use the dictionary form instead for this purpose.)

「マンガばっかり読んで（い）る」← Natural

「マンガばっかり読む」← Not natural

Comment: Ah, it makes total sense! Thanks for the answer. I've seen 「読んでる」 many times, but for some reason I never would've associated it with 「読んでて」.
Also, you've nailed it, it seems I'm not yet fully used to the "habitual action" characteristic of て/でいる.

Comment: The translation Tae Kim gives to the sentence is _"Takashi-kun **is reading** nothing but comic books... He's so uncool."_. Would it rather be _"Takashi-kun **reads** [...]"_?